# How to check if ElasticSearch is running properly

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am new to ElasticSearch and I am facing issues while connecting to ElasticSearch. Please find below details:

1. **hq** plugin and **head** plugin are showing different results:

   *Output of HQ Plugin:*
   [image: Output of HQ Plugin]

   *Output of Head Plugin:*
   [image: Output of Head Plugin]
2. When I try to connect from my scala code, I get following error:

   ```
   org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
   at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:305)
   at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:200)
   at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClient.execute(InternalTransportClient.java:106)
   at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.index(AbstractClient.java:102)
   at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.index(TransportClient.java:340)
   at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.IndexDsl$IndexDefinitionExecutable$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(IndexDsl.scala:23)
   at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.IndexDsl$IndexDefinitionExecutable$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(IndexDsl.scala:23)
   at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.Executable$class.injectFuture(Executable.scala:21)
   at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.IndexDsl$IndexDefinitionExecutable$.injectFuture(IndexDsl.scala:20)
   at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.IndexDsl$IndexDefinitionExecutable$.apply(IndexDsl.scala:23)
   at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.IndexDsl$IndexDefinitionExecutable$.apply(IndexDsl.scala:20)
   at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ElasticClient.execute(ElasticClient.scala:28)
   ```

Here is my Code which I use for connection:

```
val settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                                .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch")
                                .build()
val client = ElasticClient.remote(settings, ElasticsearchClientUri("elasticsearch://10.50.xxx.xxx:9300"))
```

3. I also checked my connection and I am able to successfully telnet 10.50.xxx.xxx on both 9200 and 9300 ports
4. I read somewhere that the problem might be with `http.cors`, So I added following lines to  `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` file on the server:

   ```
   http.cors.allow-origin: "/.*/"
   http.cors.enabled: true
   ```

   Please suggest what am I doing wrong ?

**-- Update --**
*Thanks @ Evaldas Buinauskas, It was version problem, I had installed elastic version 2.0 and was using libraries and plugins of version 1.7. I downgraded my elastic to version 1.7 and everything worked!*

Comment: Could you tell what's your elasticsearch version, head plugin and scala client versions? Elasticsearch dropped `_status` api in 2.0, which was used in head plugin to determinate cluster health, perhaps your Scala client is using that too. `_status` was replace with `_recovery`.

Comment: Thanks, It was version problem, I had installed elastic version 2.0 and was  using libraries and plugins of version 1.7. I downgraded my elastic to version 1.7 and everything worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from different Elasticsearch, head plugin and Scala client versions.

In pre 2.0 Elasticsearch still supported deprecated [_status](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/indices-status.html) endpoint (deprecated in 1.2.0)

Version 2.0 completely dropped it and replaced it with [_recovery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-recovery.html).

Both head and Scala weren't upgraded and tried to call dropped api.